# Behind the scene working of Javascript const for primitive vs objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, constants

I came across this interesting concept where `const` behave differently for `number`, `string`, `Boolean` vs `Object`, `arrays`.

```
const num1 = 10
num1 = 20 //throws error

const arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
arr1.push(5) //works
arr1.pop() //works
arr1[2] = 7 //works

arr1 = [2,3] //throws error
```

For `array` & `objects` it allows change in value but throws error in assignment. Is it mean, there is no advantage of declaring `object` or `array` as `const`, as you can change all values anytime?

If anyone can explain, I would like to know, how, behind the scene, `const` works?

Comment: [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) might be what you're after. `const` is used to prevent reassignment, but can still be useful for objects/arrays

Comment: `const` means that the variable ***cannot be reassigned***. That's it. It doesn't make the value immutable.

Comment: an object(an array is also an object) is really a pointer.. `const` means u can't mess with that pointer, but values inside can be manipulated.. `arr` can be a constant but `arr[0]` won't be

Comment: All primitives are immutable, even when using let or var. `var a = 'hello'; a[0] = 'y'; console.log(a) // 'hello;`

Comment: Also, I don't see why you say `const` works differently. `num1 = 20 //throws error` and `arr1 = [2,3] //throws error` are identical operations. Reassignments. In both cases, they are not allowed. `arr1.push(5) //works` is not a reassignment.

Answer (score 1):

The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value.
The value it holds is still immutable. Both array and object are holding some values. Those values and properties can be changed but same variable identifier cannot be reassigned.

Here arr1 is an variable identifier

```
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
arr1.push(5) //works // changing the value
arr1.pop() //works //changing the value
arr1[2] = 7 //works // changing the value
```

Here arr1 got reassigned so it is throwing an error

```
 arr1 = [2,3] //throws error // reassigning the same variable
```